# How to use use dictionary to construct another variable in r?

Tags: r, dictionary, hash

I have recently acquired a census dataset and managed to transform to R format. However, it just came to my attention that regions of the country are recorded as numbers from 901 to 911. I thought that I could create a dictionary with hash function and use it to create a separate variable that would list names of regions as characters. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: R does not have a dictionary object. Instead, use a named vector or use the `match` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:10,region = sample(901:911,size = 10,replace = TRUE))

# Option 1 - left join
 key1 <- data.frame(region = 901:911,
                    region_name = paste("Region",901:911),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
> left_join(dat,key1,by = "region")
   id region region_name
1   1    902  Region 902
2   2    902  Region 902
3   3    903  Region 903
4   4    903  Region 903
5   5    911  Region 911
6   6    909  Region 909
7   7    902  Region 902
8   8    911  Region 911
9   9    906  Region 906
10 10    905  Region 905

# Option 2 - Indexing
key2 <- setNames(paste("Region",901:911),901:911)
dat$region_name <- key2[as.character(dat$region)]
> dat
   id region region_name
1   1    902  Region 902
2   2    902  Region 902
3   3    903  Region 903
4   4    903  Region 903
5   5    911  Region 911
6   6    909  Region 909
7   7    902  Region 902
8   8    911  Region 911
9   9    906  Region 906
10 10    905  Region 905
```